# find index of element in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, indexing, submenu, getelementsbyclassname

I grab all elements by class name and create a listener for each one as follows:

```
const subnavs = document.getElementsByClassName('subnav') 
for ( let i =0 ; i <subnavs.length ; i++ ) {
   subnavs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
   purpleDiv.style.marginTop =  rect.height + 'px'
})
```

When the mouse event is triggered how do I get the index of which 'subnav' was clicked on?  This is in Wordpress so I don't have an easy way of adding an id to each subnav which would do the trick.

Comment: use event delegation via [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index just use `i` in your callback:

```
   subnavs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
       purpleDiv.style.marginTop =  rect.height + 'px'
       console.log("INDEX: ", i)
   })
```

**If you are trying to use the index to access the element later on, I would recommend the following:**

When your callback in your event listener is called it is passed a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

So if you change `function() {` to `function(event) {` you can get the specific element being moused over with [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) which is the element that triggered the 'mouseover' event.

```
   subnavs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
       purpleDiv.style.marginTop =  rect.height + 'px'
       console.log("ELEMENT: ", event.target)
   })
```

Comment: doesn't work.  i not being written to console.  Is there a closure issue?

Comment: If you're not seeing any console output, either your event listener isn't working or there is some other error (does purpleDiv exist? does rect exist?) 
Tuckers codepen demonstrates this should work so something must be up

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object:

```
const subnavs = document.getElementsByClassName('subnav') 
for ( let i =0 ; i <subnavs.length ; i++ ) {
   subnavs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
   /*** Now you can use 'e' to reference the nav triggering the listener **/
   e.style.marginTop =  rect.height + 'px'
   ***/
   purpleDiv.style.marginTop =  rect.height + 'px'
})
```

Comment: anti-pattern. use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)